# App crashes when the setContentView of searchActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a search box on the `ActionBar`. If I use `SearchView` to search a string on  the `MainActivity` it activates the `SearchActivity` which handles the search query. But when I call `setContentView()` to set the layout of the `SearchActivity` the app crashes.

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {

private TextView textview;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_search);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
    //textview=findViewById(R.id.search_result);
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }
}

public void doSearch(String query) {
    //textview.setText("You have searched for "+query);
}
}
```

This is my `MainActivity`

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.search_menu, menu );

        // Add SearchWidget.
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem( R.id.search_box ).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo( getComponentName() ) );

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
    }

    }
```

This is my `search_layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anjaleeps.loancomparison">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchActivity" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".SearchActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat crash info

Comment: what is the error in logcat

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: copy your logcat and paste here

Comment: Check your _intent_ will be _null_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending AppCompatActivity to your SearchActivity. If your intent is not null, it should work.

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

for more , you can refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity